# making reactjs interface on existing javascript program

Tags: javascript, reactjs

update // i got it up to here

```
<div>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script type="text/babel">
    class ReactUI extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>React</h2>
            <h3>Standard Deviation</h3>
            <input type="file" id="stdReact" />
            <script>
              document.getElementById('stdReact').addEventListener('change', fileChangedHandler1, false)
            </script>
            <div id="stdResultsReact"></div>
          </div>          
        )
      }
    }

    const element = <ReactUI />    

    ReactDOM.render(
      element,
      document.getElementById('root')
    )
  </script>  
</div>
```

i think everything is adopting alright expet script tag where calls function onChange

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have made javascript program to calculate Standard Deviation from csv, 
and now i need to make(remake) interface with ReactJS tried to apply line by line and got stuck at implementing script tag.

```
//html//
<div id=std>
    <h3>Standard Deviation</h3>
    <input type="file" id="std" />
    <br />
    <script>
      document.getElementById('std').addEventListener('change',fileChangedHandler1, false)
    </script>
    <div class="stdResults"></div>
</div>
```

. .

```
////////// Standard Deviation //////////

////////// Mean Calc //////////
function fSum(){
  e = event.target.result
  x = e.replace(/\n/g, ',').split(',').map(Number)
  sum = x.reduce((x, y) => x + y)
  n = x.length
  mean = sum / n
}

////////// STD Calc //////////
var stdCalc = function (event) {    
  fSum()
  xiMinusMean = 0
  sumXiMinusMean = 0
  for ( let i = 0; i<n; ++i){
    xiMinusMean = x[i]-mean
    sumXiMinusMean += (xiMinusMean * xiMinusMean)
  } 
  std = Math.sqrt(sumXiMinusMean/(n-1))
  rounded = Math.round(std * 100)/100
  $('.stdResults').html(
    '<br>SumXi : ' + sum + '<br> nXi : ' + n    + '<br> Mean : ' + mean + '<br> sum(x-mean^2) : ' + sumXiMinusMean + '<br> Standard Deviation : ' + std + '<br> Standard Deviation (2dp) : ' + rounded
  )  

}
////////// STD Handler //////////
var fileChangedHandler1 = function(event) {
  var theFile;
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = stdCalc   
  theFile = event.target.files[0]
  reader.readAsText( theFile )
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. It's not clear what you're asking. Is it possible to create a small fiddle which illustrates the problem better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working

```
class FileInput extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.onFileChange = this.onFileChange.bind(this)
  }

  onFileChange (e) {
    let file = e.target.files[0]
    let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files
    if (!files.length) {
      return
    }
    this.loadNumbers(files[0])
  }

  loadNumbers (file) {
    let reader = new window.FileReader()
    console.log(reader)
    let vm = this

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      stdCalcReact()
    }
    reader.readAsText(file)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>React</h2>
        <h3>Standard Deviation</h3>
        <input type='file' onChange={this.onFileChange} />
        <br />
        <div id="stdResultsReact"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const element = <FileInput />

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The React version of your html would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.fileChangedHandler1 = this.fileChangedHandler1.bind(this);
  }

  fileChangedHandler1(event) {
    // ... call setState and whatnot...
  }

  // Other functions in your script left as an exercise for the reader...

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="std">
        <h3>Standard Deviation</h3>
        <input type="file" id="std" onChange={this.fileChangedHandler1} />
        <br />
        <div className="stdResults"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind, this is assuming that you've already set up a build process, such as Webpack, gulp, etc. that can understand JSX.

Comment: ty for reply.. how can i apply your answer to mine? (just updated question with current react code) thanx

Comment: Take your script tag out—you don’t need it, since the event handler is being applied by the onChange prop on the input tag in my JSX example.